# Restore only Gitlab User Accounts

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

I have an issue with my Gitlab backup. I have automatic backups for my instance as well as the `gitlab-secrets.json`. I recently updated from `16.8.1-ce` to `16.9.1-ce` and now suddenly all my repos and user accounts were gone. I tried to restore my instance using the backup but something seems to have corrupted the tar and it's not working. I've given up on this by now and will just extract the repositories `.bundle` and create new ones. I'm wondering though, if there is a way to restore user(-accounts), because we don't have an E-Mail Server and I would have to re-sign-up every user manually. I tried copy+pasting the old `gitlab-secrets.json` file but this only crashed the instance. Any ideas?